# How to sort a World Cup group table in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, sorting

I'm writing an algorithm to create and sort a World Cup group table based on match data. So, given the following match data:

```
[
  { id: 1, home_team: "Honduras", away_team: "Chile", home_score: 0, away_score: 1 },
  { id: 2, home_team: "Spain", away_team: "Switzerland", home_score: 0, away_score: 1 },
  { id: 3, home_team: "Chile", away_team: "Switzerland", home_score: 1, away_score: 0 },
  { id: 4, home_team: "Spain", away_team: "Honduras", home_score: 2, away_score: 0 },
  { id: 5, home_team: "Chile", away_team: "Spain", home_score: 1, away_score: 2 },
  { id: 6, home_team: "Honduras", away_team: "Switzerland", home_score: 0, away_score: 0 }
]
```

My program will produce this (order is important):

```
[{ goals_for: 4, goals_against: 2, goal_diff: 2,  points: 6, name: "Spain" },
 { goals_for: 3, goals_against: 2, goal_diff: 1,  points: 6, name: "Chile" },
 { goals_for: 1, goals_against: 1, goal_diff: 0,  points: 4, name: "Switzerland" },
 { goals_for: 0, goals_against: 3, goal_diff: -3, points: 1, name: "Honduras" }]
```

This is great, unless there is a two-way or a three-way tie. Then the criteria becomes complex. Here it is in order of precedence:

1. Greatest number of points
2. Greatest goal diff
3. Greatest goals for

   - **IF there is a tie the following is used**
4. Greatest number of points from matches between tied teams
5. Greatest goal diff from matches between tied teams
6. Greatest goals score from matches between tied teams
7. Draw lots

## Question

My sorting function satisfies the first three criteria. How can I change it to account for cases where there is a two-way or a three-way tie?

```
  def sort
    teams.sort_by! do |team|
      [ team[:points], team[:goal_diff], team[:goals_for] ]
    end.reverse!
  end
```

### Example of 3-way tie

```
[
  { id: 1, home_team: "Algeria", away_team: "Slovenia", home_score: 2, away_score: 1 },
  { id: 2, home_team: "USA", away_team: "Slovenia", home_score: 5, away_score: 1 },
  { id: 3, home_team: "England", away_team: "Slovenia", home_score: 4, away_score: 0 },
  { id: 4, home_team: "Algeria", away_team: "USA", home_score: 3, away_score: 0 },
  { id: 5, home_team: "USA", away_team: "England", home_score: 2, away_score: 0 },
  { id: 6, home_team: "England", away_team: "Algeria", home_score: 3, away_score: 2 }
]
```

This example would eliminate Slovenia based on criteria 1 (points).

The ranks of the remaining three teams are then calculated based on a **subset** of the match data. This subset should only include matches between the tied teams. In this case, we would rebuild the table using all matches that include Algeria, England, and the USA. We exclude matches involving Slovenia.

The table should look like this:

```
| POS | TEAM        | GF | GA | GD | POINTS |
| 1   | Algeria     | 5  | 3  |  2 | 3      |
| 3   | England     | 3  | 4  | -1 | 3      |
| 2   | USA         | 2  | 3  | -1 | 3      |
```

Algeria wins on goal difference (criteria 5). England takes second spot because its `goals for` is greater than that of the USA (criteria 6).

My program actually outputs this, which is not correct, as it does not do anything about ties, and stops at criteria 3.

```
[ { goals_for: 7, goals_against: 4, goal_diff: 3, points: 6, name: "England" },
  { goals_for: 7, goals_against: 4, goal_diff: 3, points: 6, name: "Algeria" },
  { goals_for: 7, goals_against: 4, goal_diff: 3, points: 6, name: "USA" },
  { goals_for: 2, goals_against: 11, goal_diff: -9, points: 0, name: "Slovenia" }]
```

Here is the full program:

```
class Calculator
  attr_reader :games, :teams

  def initialize(games)
    defaults = { goals_for: 0, goals_against: 0, goal_diff: 0, points: 0 }
    @games = games
    @teams = games.each_with_object([]) do |game, arr|
      arr.push({ name: game[:home_team] }.merge!(defaults))
      arr.push({ name: game[:away_team] }.merge!(defaults))
    end.uniq
  end

  def build_table
    build
    sort
    return teams
  end

private

  def build
    games.each do |game|
      if game[:home_score].present? && game[:away_score].present?
        home_team = teams.detect { |team| team[:name] == game[:home_team] }
        away_team = teams.detect { |team| team[:name] == game[:away_team] }

        home_team[:goals_for]     += game[:home_score]
        home_team[:goals_against] += game[:away_score]

        away_team[:goals_for]     += game[:away_score]
        away_team[:goals_against] += game[:home_score]

        home_team[:goal_diff] = home_team[:goals_for] - home_team[:goals_against]
        away_team[:goal_diff] = away_team[:goals_for] - away_team[:goals_against]

        if game[:home_score] > game[:away_score]
          home_team[:points] += 3
        elsif game[:home_score] < game[:away_score]
          away_team[:points] += 3
        else
          home_team[:points] += 1
          away_team[:points] += 1
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def sort
    teams.sort_by! { |team| [ team[:points], team[:goal_diff], team[:goals_for] ] }.reverse!
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't see the three-way tie. In all the above cases, either points, GF, or GD are different.

Comment: @MarkThomas can you elaborate please? What's wrong with the example I gave? It's a tie insofar as the first set of criteria. But the second set resolves it, yes. Which is my question. I'm not sure how to program that part since we need to reduce the involved matches to the ones involving the tied teams only.

Comment: Criteria 2: Greatest Goal Diff. Algeria has 2, others -1.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes. I explained that in my question. I also explained why England ranked higher than the US (greatest goals for). By three-way tie here I mean with respect to the first set of criteria (1 to 3). My program does not know how to resolve the second set (4 to 7). If there are ties according to the first set, my program needs to recalculate the table based on the teams involved in the tie after criteria 1-3 are applied (so in this case matches involving Algeria, England, and USA).

Comment: Ah, I get it now. If you had included the output of your program for the example, it would have been easier to follow. I was comparing your table to the first set of criteria.

Comment: @MarkThomas Sorry about that. In this case my program would output England, Algeria, and US. I don't know what Ruby uses to Rank them in this order. In fourth it's Slovenia. The correct output would be Algeria, England, USA, Slovenia.

Comment: @MarkThomas I have added the result of my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a set of well-defined rules to determine how the teams should be ordered. One approach is to write a sort routine that implements those rules one at a time, and short-circuits when it finds a winner:

```
def compare_points(a, b)
  a[:points] <=> b[:points]
end

def compare_goal_diff(a, b)
  a[:goal_diff] <=> b[:goal_diff]
end

def compare_teams(a, b)
  comparison = compare_points(a, b)
  return comparison unless comparison.zero?

  comparison = compare_goal_diff(a, b)
  return comparison unless comparison.zero?
  # Repeat for each type of comparison
  # ...
  comparison.zero? ? flip_coin : comparison
end

teams.sort! { |a, b| compare_teams(a, b) }.reverse!
```

When comparing single values (like points), the comparison operator `<=>` is enough. For the more complex comparisons you'll need to dig into the `@games` array to determine the winner, e.g.:

```
  def compare_points_from_matches_between(a, b)
    # Hand-waving follows
    # case
    # when team A has fewer points than team B in their meetings
    #   -1
    # when team B has fewer points than team A in their meetings
    #   1
    # else
    #   0
    # end
  end
```

Apply each comparison according to your rules. At each step if the comparison is non-zero you return that value; otherwise you move on the the next step. At the end if the comparison is still zero you flip a coin.

Comment: Thank you. Is your sort routine not the same as `teams.sort_by { |t| [  t[:points], t[:goal_diff], t[:goals_for] ] }`? or have I missed something? The problem is that to break ties after criteria 1 to 3 are applied, I need to use a subset of that match data. This subset should only include matches that involve tied teams. In this case, I would need all matches not involving Slovenia, since criteria 1 to 3 eliminated them. Then I need to build a new table and apply the same sort routine on the new table (which should now involve three teams, excluding Slovenia).

Comment: You need to add the tie-breaking comparisons--that is the "hand-waving" I mentioned. Your `sort_by` routine is only comparing arrays; the `compare_teams` method is meant to allow you to add as many tie-breaking comparisons as you need, but you still have to write them. There are three tie-breaking steps, and the "coin flip"; write a method for each.

Comment: I've +1 for keeping it obvious, BUT I think there's expension required around the three-way-tie scenario, in which in order to compare two teams we need to look at the games involving **3** teams, which fact can't be determined until you've ranked all the teams, but that's what you're trying to do in the first place...

Comment: @AakashM so, in `compare_matches_between_teams` I have to go back and build a new table based on the tied teams, then apply the same comparison methods earlier? Recursion? I think I am missing something.

Comment: @Mohamad I *think* just two phases will do: a first phase using rules 1-3, then *if needed* build a new subtable with just the tied teams from phase 1, and run rules 4-6 on the subtable; finally, draw lots if needed.

Comment: +1 for the sort routine. This is a tougher problem that I expected though. I wrote a recursive method, but it still needs some work.