# Ruby reorder an array based on the contents of a subset array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this array ordered by `hash[:points]`

```
original = [{a: "Bill", points: 4}, {b: "Will", points: 3}, {c: "Gill", points: 2}, {d: "Pill", points: 1}]
```

I want to change the order of it's elements based on the order of a subset array, also ordered by `hash[:points]`.

```
subset = [{c: "Gill", points: 2}, {b: "Will", points: 1}]
```

The subset's elements are always contained in the original. But the subset's length and order come at random. It may have two, three, or four elements, in any order.

I want to incorporate the order of the subset into the original array. This can be done by reordering the original, or recreating the original in the correct order. Either will do. But I don't want to merge them. The `keys` and `values` in the subset are not important, just the order of the elements.

For example, the above subset should produce this.

```
# Bill and Pill retain their original position
# Gill and Will swap places as per ordering of the subset
[{a: "Bill", points: 4}, {c: "Gill", points: 2}, {b: "Will", points: 3}, {d: "{Pill}", points: 1}]
```

Another example with this subset: `[{c: "Gill", points: 3}, {b: "Will", points: 2}, {a: "Bill", points: 1}]`

```
# Pill remains at index 3 since it was not in the subset
# Gill, Will, and Bill are reordered based on the order of the subset 
[{c: "Gill", points: 3}, {b: "Will", points: 2}, {a: "Bill", points: 1}, {d: "Pill", points: 1}]
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff for the past couple of hours, but I'm finding this harder than it looks.

Comment: `{b: 17}` is not in the original..

Comment: @ArupRakshit sorry, I'm an idiot.

Comment: *The keys and values in the subset are not important, just the order of the elements.* - Then ordering will be done based on what..?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I want to keep the order of the original array, but insert any order changes in the subset. Does that make sense? If not, I should delete my question and reword it.

Comment: What is the supposed order of the elements which are not part of the subset?

Comment: @UriAgassi they remain as they are. They should not be affected. Look at example 1. `a` and `d` remain in place, but `c` and `b` swap places.

Comment: @UriAgassi Is my question clear, or should I delete it and rephrase it?

Comment: One more thing subset array will be having the same key/value as per the original right ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit no. This is why it's important not to merge them. There are other keys, and I don't want the original be over written. I just want it to be reordered. I know this sounds weird, but trust me, there is a very good reason for it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Basically, the original array must remain exactly the same, but in corporate the order of the subset into its own elements.

Comment: @ArupRakshit if you are curious about this, see [this comment I made on Uri's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941389/ruby-reorder-an-array-based-on-the-contents-of-a-subset-array/23941676#comment-36878478).

Comment: If you and @Arup are both idiots, I am one as well. Let's start a club!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not sure about Arup, but I certainly am. I was so concentrated on solving this issue that I wrote the question entirely wrong. Embarrassing.

Comment: @CarySwoveland if it were ever in doubt, here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941389/ruby-reorder-an-array-based-on-the-contents-of-a-subset-array#comment-36881012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution has two steps:

1. Collect the relevant elements from the original array, and sort them according to the subset order.
2. Replace them in the original array with the new order.

Here is the code:

```
mapped_elements = subset.map { |i| original.find { |j| j.keys == i.keys } }

result = original.map do |i|
  if subset.find { |j| j.keys == i.keys }
    mapped_elements.shift
  else
    i
  end
end
```

For `subset = [{c: "Gill", points: 2}, {b: "Will", points: 1}]` the result will be:

```
[{a: "Bill", points: 4}, {c: "Gill", points: 2}, {b: "Will", points: 3}, {d: "{Pill}", points: 1}]
```

For `subset = [{c: "Gill", points: 3}, {b: "Will", points: 2}, {a: "Bill", points: 1}]` the result will be:

```
[{c: "Gill", points: 3}, {b: "Will", points: 2}, {a: "Bill", points: 4}, {d: "Pill", points: 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you. To clarify my question, I added an additional key to the hashes in the array. It's used for sorting. I feel like a jerk for not including that at the start, but I did not think it mattered. Sorry about that.

Comment: Just curious, does providing another hash key make much difference? I omitted that because I felt it was not relevant. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: My solution works while _all the keys_ in the item in `original` appear also in `subset`, since the code checks for `j.keys == i.keys`. If only the original had `:points`, the code would not have worked.

Comment: OK. If you are curious about why I need this... it's for sorting world cup tables. The first round of sorting is easy: points, goal diff, and then goals for. If you have a tie, you need to build another table using a subset of group matches that involve only tied teams. This new table is the subset here. When it comes back, it needs to be used to reorder the original without over writing their values. See this: http://webhome.csc.uvic.ca/~haron/FIFA/#fifa and my [related question on here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923864/how-to-sort-a-world-cup-group-table-in-ruby)

Comment: In other words, the original array is an accurate table. But it needs to be reordered in the event of a tie, based on on a new table that only involves the tied teams. But the original table must remain intact, as it has info based on all the games, not a subset of games between tied teams.

Comment: Interestingly enough this doesn't work if you add a third key to the objects. Even if all the objects have that 3rd key. Why is that? In particular, the `mapped_elements` is what coughs up.

Comment: I got this to work by changing the comparison oprator to frm `i.keys` to `i[:foo]`.

Comment: The accepted answer's output is wrong although it matches the mistaken? output in the op. For instance, Bill has 4 pts in the original, so he still has to end up with 4 pts in the result.  According to the op, the data in the original has to be preserved.

Comment: @7stud - you got me... I copied the output (with the mistake) from the OP - my IRB has awesome print, and I got lazy :-p

Answer (score 1):

```
I know this sounds weird, but trust me, there is a very good reason for it.
```

Sorry, no can do.  I think you chose the wrong structure for your hashes to begin with.  I can't think of any reason why you would create hashes which have different keys for each person's name.  When you are having trouble manipulating the data structure that you initially chose, then you should think about restructuring your data.

```
teams = { 
  Bill: {group: "a", points: 4},
  Will: {group: "b", points: 3},
  Gill: {group: "c", points: 2},
  Pill: {group: "d", points: 1},
}

teams_subset = {
  Gill: {group: "c", points: 3}, 
  Will: {group: "b", points: 2}, 
  Bill: {group: "a", points: 1},
}

subset_names =  teams_subset.keys
new_teams = {}

teams.each do |team, stats|
  if teams_subset.include? team
    next_subset_name = subset_names.shift
    new_teams[next_subset_name] = teams[next_subset_name]
  else 
    new_teams[team] = stats
  end
end 

p new_teams

--output:--
{:Gill=>{:group=>"c", :points=>2}, :Will=>{:group=>"b", :points=>3}, :Bill=>{:group=>"a", :points=>4}, :Pill=>{:group=>"d", :points=>1}}
```

Or even:

```
teams =  [
  {name: 'Bill', stats: {group: "a", points: 4}},
  {name: 'Will', stats: {group: "b", points: 3}},
  {name: 'Gill', stats: {group: "c", points: 2}},
  {name: 'Pill', stats: {group: "d", points: 1}},
]
```

**Based on your new revelations**, I would just use a quasi Schwarzian Transform to convert your data to this form:

```
"Bill"=>{:name=>"Bill", :points=>4}
```

...then apply code similar to what I posted above, like this:

```
require 'set'

teams =  [
  {name: 'Bill', points: 4},
  {name: 'Will', points: 3},
  {name: 'Gill', points: 2},
  {name: 'Pill', points: 1},
]

remapped_teams = {}

teams.each do |hash|
  name = hash[:name]
  remapped_teams[name] = hash
end

p remapped_teams

#--output:--
#{"Bill"=>{:name=>"Bill", :points=>4}, "Will"=>{:name=>"Will", :points=>3}, "Gill"=>{:name=>"Gill", :points=>2}, "Pill"=>{:name=>"Pill", :points=>1}}

teams_subset = [
  {name: 'Gill', points: 3}, 
  {name: 'Will', points: 2}, 
  {name: 'Bill', points: 1},
]

subset_names = teams_subset.map do |hash|
  hash[:name]
end
subset_names_lookup = Set.new(subset_names)

new_team_order = remapped_teams.map do |(name, hash)|
  if subset_names_lookup.include? name
    remapped_teams[subset_names.shift]
  else 
    hash
  end
end 

p new_team_order

--output:--
[{:name=>"Gill", :points=>2}, {:name=>"Will", :points=>3}, {:name=>"Bill", :points=>4}, {:name=>"Pill", :points=>1}]
```

Comment: You can officially call me an idiot. I spent so much time trying to find a solution that when I wrote my examples, I wrote the hashes with different keys. The reality is, all the example hashes have `name: "Gill"` etc... instad of `a:, b:, c:`.

Comment: The actual structure is `[{name: "Foo", points: 1},{ name: "Bar", points: 1}]` etc...

Comment: @Mohamad, what are the keys for the names?

Comment: This is a real example: `{ name: "USA", goal_diff: 3, points: 6 }`, all the hashes have identical keys. To keep things simple I omitted a lot of data, and in the process I confused myself and everyone else.

Comment: +1 one for the effort. For the actual application of this, see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941389/ruby-reorder-an-array-based-on-the-contents-of-a-subset-array/23941676#comment-36878478) in this thread.

Comment: All this probably means there's a simpler solution, yet I was still not able to figure it out. I need a break. My brains are wracked. To my credit, I have a terrible flu!

Comment: As I showed, the problem is much simpler if you use the team names as the hash keys.  Get well soon.

Comment: @Mohamad, see my edits for a solution with your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.  This is based on the understanding that each hash in `original` and in `subset` contain the same two keys: `:name` (say) and `:points`.

**Code**

```
def reorder(original, subset)
  orig_hash = original.each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g[h[:name]] = h }
  subset_names = subset.map { |h| h[:name] }
  orig_hash.map { |k,v|
    subset_names.include?(k) ? orig_hash[subset_names.rotate!.last] : v }
end
```

**Examples**

```
original = [{name: "Bill", points: 4}, {name: "Will", points: 3},
            {name: "Gill", points: 2}, {name: "Pill", points: 1}]
```

*#1*

```
subset   = [{name: "Gill", points: 2}, {name: "Will", points: 1}]
reorder(original, subset)
  #=> [{:name=>"Bill", :points=>4}, {:name=>"Gill", :points=>2},
  #    {:name=>"Will", :points=>3}, {:name=>"Pill", :points=>
```

*#2*

```
subset   = [{name: "Gill", points: 3}, {name: "Will", points: 2},
            {name: "Bill", points: 1}]

reorder(original, subset)
  #=> [{:name=>"Gill", :points=>2}, {:name=>"Will", :points=>3},
  #    {:name=>"Bill", :points=>4}, {:name=>"Pill", :points=>1}]
```

**Explanation**

The following calculations are performed for `original` above and

```
subset = [{c: "Gill", points: 2}, {b: "Will", points: 1}]
```

Construct this hash from `original`:

```
orig_hash = original.each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g[h[:name]] = h }
  #=> {"Bill"=>{:name=>"Bill", :points=>4}, "Will"=>{:name=>"Will", :points=>3},
      "Gill"=>{:name=>"Gill", :points=>2}, "Pill"=>{:name=>"Pill", :points=>1}}
```

and an array of the values of `:name` from `subsets`:

```
subset_names = subset.map { |h| h[:name] }
  #=> ["Gill", "Will"]
```

All that remains is to map each `k=>v` element of `orig_hash` to either `v` (if `subset_names` does not have the key `k`) or to the first element of `subset_names`.  As we cannot delete the latter from `subset_names`, I have chosen to rotate the array by +1 and then retrieve that value from the last position.  That way, the next key in `subset_names` will then be positioned properly, at the beginning of the array.

```
orig_hash.map { |k,v| subset_names.include?(k) ? orig_hash[subset_names.rotate!.last] : v }
  #=> [{:name=>"Bill", :points=>4}, {:name=>"Gill", :points=>2},
  #    {:name=>"Will", :points=>3}, {:name=>"Pill", :points=>1}]
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, thank you. I mentioned in some other comments that that the hash keys are identical. I did not change question because some people had already answered it in it's flawed state. So, my examples should have all had the same keys: `[{ a: "Bill"},{ a: "Will" }]` instead of `[{ a: "Bill" }, { b: "Will" }]` notice the keys should be `a` and `a` not `a` and `b`. Hence my calling myself an idiot :D -- this is pretty neat, though! Thanks for contributing.

Comment: I updated my answer to conform with your clarification of the problem.  In future, I suggest you clarify by editing you question, rather than trying to do so in comments. It is easy for the reader to miss some comments, and readers will often skip comments made to an answer, on the assumption that those comments pertain only to that answer and not to the question itself.  When you edit, it is helpful to indicate with an **Edit:**, or somesuch.